# Crontab PHP execution

Tags: php, xml, cron

Crontab doesn't execute my php file.

I've set up my "crontab -e" as follows

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/books_loader/cron_jobs/CronBooksLoader.php
```

As you can see I want it to run every minute.
My php folder is as it is "/usr/bin/php". My "CronBooksLoader.php" is at the proper directory and it has all the necessary permissions(even 777).

The "CronBooksLoader.php" contains this code

```
<?php
namespace BooksLoader\Base;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$bookObj = new Books();

$loadFiles = $bookObj->load('../xmlData');
$result = $bookObj->upsert();
```

Which when I start in the browser(http://127.0.0.1/books_loader/cron_jobs/CronBooksLoader.php) successfully loads my data from the XML files in that directory.

I'm not 100% sure if the file is not executed or just that cron doesn't know what to do.

*******UPDATE*******

After all the comments bellow. Cron runs and creates logs.
I get error

```
PHP Warning:  require(../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/books_loader/cron_jobs/CronBooksLoader.php on line 4
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/books_loader/cron_jobs/CronBooksLoader.php on line 4
```

But I cant figure out how else to give a correct path to it. I want it to remain
relative.

Comment: First of all, setting permissions to 777 is never a good idea for a php file. Use 755 which should be sufficient

Comment: I know @SvenHakvoort I was just desperate at that point...

Comment: Allright :) just to be sure xD could you try logging the result with `>> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1` after the php command in your crontab? So: `*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/books_loader/cron_jobs/CronBooksLoader.php >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1`

Comment: check the error log

Comment: Remember that when using the dots in the file path, it translates it from the path the script is run in, not where the script resides. Either change the require to be an absolute path, or add a cd to your crontab to the script directory.

Comment: i think you should include files like - require (__DIR__.'../vendor/autoload.php' ); to make sure that file included properly.

Comment: Turns out that it doesn't create  /var/log/cron.log . I waited for 2 min :D. So what could it be?

Comment: check apache server error log file

Comment: Add error checking to the file and then run it manually from the command line.

Comment: @Beni is `cron` running at all? Is it *installed*? What does `which cron` say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR if you don't know better, use `curl`, `lynx` or `wget`**.

The script execution takes place in **two very different environments** depending on whether you use a HTTP client or the PHP binary.

When you invoke it through curl, lynx, or wget, it executes **within the web server's environment**. When you invoke it through the PHP binary, it executes in the commandline environment (CLI).

One of the most obvious differences is that the **work directory is different**, therefore this line:

```
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
```

means two different things when you run it in /var/www/yoursite/htdocs or when you run it in /tmp (cron's work dir is usually there).

There are **lots** of other differences. Usually you would use a specific "harness" script that modifies the environment to make it mimic a Web request, and run your script through that. Or you would use a completely different approach in CLI scripts (different DB connection, etc.).

If you aren't prepared to do either, then it's way better to use `curl`.

Even then, verify that the hostname matches (the machine might not "know" what it's web site address corresponds to, or might not connect to it properly. You might need to either add the web name (e.g. "www.yoursite.com") in /etc/hosts with an address of 127.0.0.1, and/or add a listening port on the loopback interface and a 127.0.0.1 alias for the web site. Failing that, you'd notice that "curl http://www.yoursite.com/cron.php" does not connect, times out, or reports some HTTP error.

Also: in cron scripts, always be sure to add a "2>&1" redirection to capture any stderr messages and have them mailed to you:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/curl http://www.yoursite.com/cron_jobs/CronBooksLoader.php 2>&1
```

(*/1 is the same as *)

=harness example

Not so much a harness than a modification to a file that needs to be executed in both contexts.

```
<?php
    if (php_sapi_name() === 'cli') {
        // Simulate a Web call.

        $dir   = dirname(__FILENAME__);
        // We must know how deep in the Web hierarchy this file is,
        // and the CLI does not know. We must tell it.
        // The root web directory has depth 0.
        $depth = 1;
        while($depth--) {
            $dir = dirname($dir);
        }
        chdir($dir);

        // Prepare a $_SERVER
        $_SERVER = array(
            'REMOTE_ADDR' => '127.0.0.2',
            // Add as needed.
        );
    }
?>
```

Comment: * * * * * cd /var/www/html/books_loader/vendor; /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/books_loader/cron_jobs/CronBooksLoader.php > /tmp/php.log 2>&1 works perfectly but I'm still pissed that I can't do it without "CD" command to choose the vendor folder. Is there a way to make the paths remain relative but work both for cron and web ?

Comment: @Beni added to answer. You need to modify the CronBooksLoader file though.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure cron is installed on your current machine.

On CentOS/RHEL:

`yum install cronie`

On Linux/Unix:

`apt-get install cron`

Try using cron on Linux/Unix with `crontab -e`

See answers about cron for more detail : https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it

Comment: 100% installed. Don't need to install it.

Comment: Try running `php /var/www/html/books_loader/cron_jobs/CronBooksLoader.php` does the script run?

Answer (score 0):

On certain shared hosting where they may have cPanel running, and using 1H, your crons could be running in a different environment. It would mean you are running in a jailed environment (like can't access files outside your home directory) or limiting your memory and such. See this page for details:
http://docs.1h.com/index.php?title=Crond

The short of it:

> Exclude an account from the chrooted environment
>
> To exclude a certain user from the chrooted environment you just have
>   to access the cron.exclude folder and create the following empty file:
>
> /var/spool/cron.exclude/USER.chroot

and

> Exclude an account from global limits
>
> To exclude a certain user from the global limits you need to create
>   the following file:
>
> /var/spool/cron.exclude/USER.limits